# Setting contact picture from linked contact

Tags: contacts, viber-messenger, contact-photo

I use [Local Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.psencik.simple) as my main address book. Several of my contacts are linked to different address books (e.g. LinkedIn, Skype, Whatsapp, Viber).

In my case, I found a contact having a very beautiful photo in Viber but I chose to set an old ugly picture in my address book

The question is: how do I tell Android to select the contact picture to display for a given contact not from Gallery/Camera apps but from that same contact's linked Viber account?

The question can be generalized and rephrased to cover not only Viber:

> how do I tell Android to select the contact picture to display for a given contact not from Gallery/Camera apps but from one of that same contact's linked accounts?

Comment: It seems that the app "Local Sync" doesn't exist any more in the Google Play store.

Comment: yes, rip Local Sync. The best Android/Outlook synchronizer I ever found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer, which is a little tricky.

## In general

When you need to set a default picture t oa contact who is linked to others, simply press <kbd>MENU</kbd> and go to `Defaults` menu. There you have the `Caller ID` setting in which you can choose the picture being displayed on call.

## In the Viber case

That is not possible, since Viber doesn't actually create linked accounts, unlike Whatsapp. If the application that allows people to set a photo to themselves and manages contacts doesn't implement writing to address book that won't be possible

Comment: I don't see a "Defaults" menu. Could you share a screenshot of where you found this menu?

Comment: I discovered that it depends on the Android Contacts application in use, which varies among Android version and phone vendor

Answer (score 1):

For Viber, use Viber Contact Photo Sync. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.booleanaxis.vibercontactphotosync2

For Whatsapp use:
[Contact Photo Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rm.android.wcps)